# Is it possible to use VBA to make a conditional copy of the formula from the active cell down the column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to implement a VBA Code to work with multiple different sheets, for example:  it starts by looking for a certain number in the first row, once it's found, it jumps to that column and types a certain formula into the 2nd cell in that column, so far it works good, But the issue is that I wanna make it to Autofill that formula down the column if the first cell in that row contains data.

Like if A2 is not blank, continue the auto fill the cell in the active column (let's say the active column is D, then the it would fill the Cell d2 if a2 not blank) and stops once the cell in A Column is blank .. etc

So, Is it possible?

```
Sub Macro1()

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Find(What:="156", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "= "Formula will be here""
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Might be best to save a copy of your workbook before running the code below.

Maybe something like this is what you're after. If `Find` found something in column `D`, then it puts the dummy formula in the range `D2:D?`, where `?` is whatever the last row in column `A` is (which I think is what you described).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' Can you refer to the workbook and worksheet by name? Please do if possible

    With ws
        Dim cellFound As Range
        Set cellFound = .Rows(1).Find(What:="156", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        If cellFound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("The value was not found in the first row of sheet '" & ws.Name & "'. Code will stop running now")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range(cellFound.Offset(1), .Cells(lastRow, cellFound.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = "=""Formula will be here"""
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain what's this all about: "=""Formula will be here""".

Comment: @VBasic2008, I think if you check the code provided in the question (towards the very end), it just says something like `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= "Formula will be here""`. So I've done something very similar. I presume it's a temporary dummy formula and OP will replace it with something else later -- unless I'm misreading something.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I thought there might be a "=" or a formula issue. BTW I've tested your code and it fails only when there is no data in Column A i.e. A2 is empty, when it overwrites the cell in found column in first row and adds another formula below it. Strange behavior. Try to fix it or not.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks for testing, will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple code, I think it will satisfy your needs:

```
Sub Macro1()


Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Find(What:="156", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    col_Num = ActiveCell.Column
    total_Rows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    Cells(2, col_Num).Select
    Cells(2, col_Num) = "=Put your Formula here"
    begin_Cell = Cells(2, col_Num).Address(False, False)
    end_Cell = Cells(total_Rows, col_Num).Address(False, False)
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(begin_Cell & ":" & end_Cell)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways to locate a column header label although I'm unclear on why you are using the LookAt:=xlPart argument. It seems to me you should not have to 'wildcard' the search but a 'wild card' search can be accommodated.

```
Sub FindnFill()

    dim m as variant

    with worksheets("sheet1")

        m = application.match("*156*", .rows(1), 0)
        if not iserror(m) then

            if not isempty(.cells(2, "A")) then
                .range(.cells(2, m), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(0, m-1)).formula = _
                   "=""formula goes here"""
            else
                .cells(2, m).formula = _
                   "=""formula goes here"""
            end if

        end if

    end with

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Find & Fill

### About the Find Method

- **It is best practice to always set the following three parameters, because they
  are saved each time they are used.**
- **LookIn** - If you use `xlFormulas`, it will find e.g. `=A2 + 156`, which you don't want.
- **LookAt** - If you use `xlPart` it will find e.g. `1567`, which you don't want.
- **SearchOrder** - Not important, since a row is being searched.
- Additionally **SearchDirection** is by **default** `xlNext` and can therefore safely be omitted.
- Additionally **MatchCase** is by **default** `False` and can therefore safely be omitted.
- Additionally **SearchFormat** - To use it you previously have to set `Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat` and can therefore safely be omitted.

## The Code

```
Sub FindFill()

  Const cDblFind As Double = 156             ' Found Value
  Const cLngRow As Long = 1                  ' Found Row Number
  Const cVntColumn As Variant = "A"          ' First Column Letter/Number
  Const cStrFormula As String = "=RC[-1]+5"  ' Formula

  Dim objFound As Range   ' Found Column Cell Range
  Dim lngRow As Long      ' First Column Non-empty Rows

  With ActiveSheet.Rows(cLngRow)

    ' Check if cell below cell in First Column and Found Row is empty.
    If .Parent.Cells(cLngRow, cVntColumn).Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    ' Calculate First Column Non-empty Rows.
    lngRow = .Parent.Cells(cLngRow, cVntColumn).End(xlDown).Row - cLngRow

    ' Find cell in Found Row containing Found Value.
    Set objFound = .Find(What:=cDblFind, After:=.Cells(.Row, .Columns.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, Searchorder:=xlByRows)

    If Not objFound Is Nothing Then
      ' Write Formula to Found Column Range
      objFound.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lngRow).FormulaR1C1 = cStrFormula
    End If

  End With

End Sub
```